# CSS, shrink-wrapped nowrap div contained in absolute, centered on absolute, below absolute

Tags: html, css

And here I was thinking I was getting good at CSS...

**CSS**

```
#container{
    /* given */
    position:absolute;
    left:100px;top:10px;
    width:200px;height:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
#tipper{
    /* be below container */
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-30px;
    width:100%;
    overflow:visible; 
    border:1px solid blue;
}
#tips{
    /* component */
    position:relative;
    margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
    border:1px solid green;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container" title="cannot modify styling">
    <div id="tipper" title="helper wrapper? to be below container">
        <div id="tips" title="must shrink and grow and remain centered horizontally">
            tips tips tips tips tips tips tips tips tips
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

**Requirements**

1. #tips should be below #container, but must be reside in #container
2. #tips should be horizontally centered on container
3. #tips should grow horizontally with its content, and shrink horizontally to its content
4. #tips width should be able to exceed container width
5. No javascript?

**Summary**

Need a tip component that displays a non-wrapping single line of text. The component must have a containment box that grows and shrinks with its text (styling of this box is a req.).
Component must reside in container, but appear below it, and it must be horizontally centered on container regardless of width of tip text content.

**Other**

Container styling is a given, you cannot change its position:absolute, etc.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9NPcs/3/)

Comment: Can `#container` have additional HTML added within it? And have its dimensions applied to that child rather than on the container itself? Otherwise, I don't see a CSS-only solution for the behaviour you're desiring. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/9NPcs/6/

Comment: @Serlite I got it now, the icky solution that will work is a transform. See my answer.

Comment: Oh, okay, I see. I guess I must have misinterpreted what you meant by "#tips should be horizontally centered on container" - I assumed you meant the center of `#tips`, not the left edge, haha.

Comment: @Setlite Yes, center of tips is always at center of container. Maybe my omission of vendor prefixes for `transform` is not making it so in your browser?

Comment: Ah, yes, that seems to be the case. I eagerly await the day when browsers across the board implement these CSS features in a standardized manner...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer I have here is a translate.

```
#container{
    /* given */
    position:absolute;
    left:100px;top:10px;
    width:200px;height:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
#tipper{
    /* be below container */
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-10px;
    width:100%;
    overflow:visible; 
    border:1px solid blue;
}
#tips{
    /* component */
    position:absolute;
    display:table;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,0px);
    white-space:nowrap;
    border:1px solid green;
}
```

[Solution Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9NPcs/7/)